# python socket send from one thread and read from another?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety

I know sockets are thread safe in general, but is it possible to use a single socket across two threads where one thread only ever calls `.sendto` and the other `.recvfrom`? Or would I still need to use a lock/multiple sockets on the same port?

Comment: I don't know if you can do this with sockets.  But why not use a Queue?  http://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: This is perfectly allowable. In-fact I'd recommend it.